# Comprehension with a Tuple and List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was curious if there is a way to turn the for loop block into a comprehension, but I was a little stumped since it contains a tuple and list.append().

```
flip_roll_list = []
for n in range(n_times):
    temp_tuple = (flip_coin(), roll_die())
    flip_roll_list.append(temp_tuple)
return(flip_roll_list)
```

Comment: `return [(flip_coin(), roll_die()) for _ in xrange(n_times)]`

Answer (score 4):

Simple build the 2-tuple at every iteration of the *list comprehension*:

```
flip_roll_list = [(flip_coin(), roll_die()) for _ in range(n_times)]
```

Comment: @DYZ Looks like you actually came first: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46124895/timeline

Comment: Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, not sure how I missed this! You guys are the best.

Answer (score 2):

`flip_roll_list = [(flip_coin(), roll_die()) for _ in range(n_times)]`